# Reshaping images - -1 and 1 as arguments to reshape method

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

I have been learning Augmentation on ASL dataset where I have been asked to reshape the images of size 28x28.

The code looks as below

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
```

what does -1 and 1 represent in the above?

Comment: `1` simply means `1`. that's it. `-1` means the quotient when you _divide_ `x_train.size` to other numbers, ie: `x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.size//28//28//1,28,28,1)`

Comment: in case you are still confused about the use of `1`, try `print(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3))` and `print(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3,1))`